# Program crash caused by debug watches on uninitialized boost::optional's content: is it a bug in the adapter, in boost::optional, or where?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, vscode-debugger, watch, boost-optional

The repro are simple and shown in the screencast below.

In essence:

- write and compile (`g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g ...`) a program (e.g. the one below) featuring an empty `boost::optional`, say `b`,
- put a breakpoint anywhere,
- start the program with the debugger, with the adapter `vscode-cpptools`, and wait for it to reach the breakpoint,
- instantiate a watch on `*b`.

The program will crash with the following self-explanatory error:

```
debugging: /usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:1271:
boost::optional<T>::reference_type boost::optional<T>::get()
[with T = int; reference_type = int&]: Assertion `this->is_initialized()' failed.
```

What I don't understand is that the *debuggee itself* is not invoking UB. Only the watch is, so why is the *debuggee* crashing? What "actor" is responsible for it?

Considering that the problem is fixed by one or both of

- switching from `boost::optional` to `std::optional`
- switching from `vscode-cpptools` to `CodeLLDB`

I'd say that the bug is either in `boost::optional` or `vscode-cpptools`; actually, since I don't think either should make assumption on the other, I'd be tempted to say that the bug is in both.

---

Here's the example program I used in the screencast below:

```cpp
#include <boost/none.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto s = std::optional<int>{};
    auto b = boost::optional<int>{};
    if (s) {
        std::cout << *s << std::endl;
    }
    if (b) {
        std::cout << *b << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

---

Here's a screencast showing my observations:
[image: asciicast]

---

Additionally, I tried with just cli `gdb`, and I can reproduce the same issue too:
[image: asciicast]

Comment: Sorry unrelated comment. What program did you use for screencasting?

Comment: Post code as code, not as image/screencast.

Comment: Most likely, your code *does* have undefined behavior. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*): "The behavior is undefined if `*this` does not contain a value."

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri, [`asciinema`](https://asciinema.org/).

Comment: @j6t, added the example code.

Comment: @j6t, where is my code accessing an empty optional? It isn't. The watch is.

Comment: If your debugger malfunctions, you may observe anything at all, including debugger crashes, debuggee crashes, or nasal daemons.

Comment: @fabian, you write _you should not use this code in a real program_, but which code? There is no code in the C++ snippet I shared that is trying to dereference the null optional.